# get string from Enum to form Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, enums

I had an issue with hiding form, I have driverType array in my enum. How can I pass the string from enum to driverform and when i choose PARTTIME, it will hide basic-salary form ?

Here's my enum code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\Enums;

final class DriverType {

const EMPLOYED = 0;
const RENTAL = 1;

public static function getList() {
    return [
        DriverType::FULLTIME,
        DriverType::PARTIME,
    ];
}

public static function getArray() {
    $result = [];
    foreach (self::getList() as $arr) {
        $result[$arr] = self::getString($arr);
    }
    return $result;
}

public static function getString($val) {
    switch ($val) {

        case 0:
            return "FULLTIME";
        case 1:
            return "PARTTIME";
    }
}

}

?>
```

here's my DriverController code :

```
public function render(View $view, $route = null, $obj = null, $method = 'POST') {
$driverTypeList = DriverType::getArray();
$view->with(compact('driverTypeList'));
return parent::render($view, $route, $obj, $method);
}
```

here's my driver form code :

```
<div id="basic-salary" class="form-group">
     <label>Basic Salary:</label>
     {!! Form::text('basic_salary', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>

<div id="Type-option" value="Type-option" class="form-group">
     <label>Type:</label>
     {!! Form::select('type', $driverTypeList, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
var select = $('#Type-option');
select.on('change', function() {
if (select.val() == "PARTTIME") {
$('#basic-salary').hide();
} else {
$('#basic-salary').show();
}
});
});
</script>
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var select = $('#Type-option');
```

you have written selector to the div tag. jQuery on change function should work with selectbox element not with div element.

```
Form::select('type', $driverTypeList, 'null', array('class' => 'form-control','id' => 'ID_HERE'));
```

then do your selector like this

```
var select = $('#ID_HERE');
```

Comment: sorry not working.I think the problem is how to pass the string to form

Comment: can you write what is showed on your browser html source code with inspect element in selectbox?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (self::getList() as $arr) {
    $result[$arr] = self::getString($arr);
}
```

also think need to be above code replace with

```
foreach (self::getList() as $arr =>$val) {
    $result[$arr] = self::getString($arr);
}
```

because as I see your getString function should get index.